# Combinar elementos en un switch en PHP

Tags: php

Buenas.
Estoy pasando por un foreach que recorre una serie de datos y quiero meterlos en un array de una manera concreta.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto:

```
    switch ($mes_registrado){
    case "01":
        $array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
        $array[2] = "Enero";
        break;
    case "02":
        $array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
        $array[3] = "Febrero";
        break;
    case "03":
        $array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
        $array[4] = "Marzo";
        break;
    case "04":
        $array[5] = "2do Trimestre";
        $array[6] = "Abril";
        break;
    case "05":
        $array[5] = "2do Trimestre";
        $array[7] = "Mayo";
        break;
    case "06":
        $array[5] = "2do Trimestre";
        $array[8] = "Junio";
        break;
    case "07":
        $array[9] = "3er Trimestre";
        $array[10] = "Julio";
        break;
    case "08":
        $array[9] = "3er Trimestre";
        $array[11] = "Agosto";
        break;
    case "09":
        $array[9] = "3er Trimestre";
        $array[12] = "Septiembre";
        break;
    case "10":
        $array[13] = "4to Trimestre";
        $array[14] = "Octubre";
        break;
    case "11":
        $array[13] = "4to Trimestre";
        $array[15] = "Noviembre";
        break;
    case "12":
        $array[13] = "4to Trimestre";
        $array[16] = "Diciembre";
        break;
}
```

Como se puede ver, en este listado de meses, me gustaría por ejemplo, que cuando fuera case 01, case 02 y case 03, agregara 1er Trimestre en su correspondiente array. E igualmente, en cada case introduzca el mes que le corresponde.

En definitiva, quiero que cada case haga lo que le corresponde y que agrupaciones de case hagan una cosa en comun, dado el caso que entren en dichas agrupaciones. Todo ello en un mismo switch.

Habia pensado en hacer un switch dentro del propio switch:

```
switch ($mes_registrado){
case "01":
case "02":
case "03":
    $array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
    switch ($mes_registrado){
        case "01":
            $array[2] = "Enero";
            break;
        case "02":
            $array[3] = "Febrero";
            break;
        case "03":
            $array[4] = "Marzo";
            break;
    }
    break;
    ...
```

Pero no se si esto es muy farragoso o chapucero, o a lo mejor no hay otro modo de hacerlo. También pensé en hacerlo con "if", pero veo el mismo asunto, debo hacer "if" anidados.

**ACTUALIZADO**

Dándole vueltas, estoy viendo la posibilidad de hacerlo así:

```
if($mes_registrado=="01"||$mes_registrado=="02"||$mes_registrado=="03"){
    $array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
    switch ($mes_registrado){
        case "01":
            $array[2] = "Enero";
            break;
        case "02":
            $array[3] = "Febrero";
            break;
        case "03":
            $array[4] = "Marzo";
            break;
    }
} else if($mes_registrado=="04"||$mes_registrado=="05"||$mes_registrado=="06"){
    $array[1] = "2do Trimestre";
    switch ($mes_registrado){
        case "04":
            $array[2] = "Abril";
            break;
        case "05":
            $array[3] = "Mayo";
            break;
        case "06":
            $array[4] = "Junio";
            break;
    }
} ...
```

No se cual método puede ser mejor. La idea es tener la menor cantidad de código y de la manera mas clara posible (y lo que fuera mas óptimo, claro, se pide mucho jeje).

Un saludo

Comment: no te convendría tener más un arreglo así de ["1er Trimestre" => ['enero', 'febrero, 'marzo''], '2do Trimeste' ...] ?

Comment: Lo quiero hacer así porque este array lo voy a usar de lista para mostrarlo en pantalla ---> 1er Trimestre - Enero - Febrero - Marzo - 2do Trimestre - Abril ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = intval($fact_mes_registrado);
$meses = [NULL,"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
$trimestre = [NULL, "1er", "2do", "3er"];
$arreglo = [];
$arreglo[] = $trimestre[ceil($num/3)].' Trimestre';
$arreglo[] = $meses[$num];
print_r($arreglo);
```

Esta en mi opinión es la que menos código ocuparía, aunque si lo meterás en un for each como te mencionó puede quedar mejor así

```
$fact_mes_array = ["03", "07", "09", "01"];
$meses = [NULL,"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"];
$trimestre = [NULL, "1er", "2do", "3er", "4to"];
$arreglo = [];
foreach($fact_mes_array as $fact_mes_registrado){
    $num = intval($fact_mes_registrado);
    $arreglo[$trimestre[ceil($num/3)].' Trimestre'][] = $meses[$num];
}
print_r($arreglo);

foreach($arreglo as $trimestre => $meses){
    echo $trimestre." : ";
    foreach($meses as $mes) {
        echo $mes.', ';
    }
    echo "; \n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi intento de hacer el mínimo código posible, adaptado de un código que usé una vez pero con fechas en inglés y con más cálculos metidos. Por ahí te sirve para sacar alguna idea :)

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'es_ES.UTF-8', 'Spanish_Spain.1252');
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('es_ES', NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
$trimestres = array_chunk(range(1, 12), 3);

foreach ($trimestres as $key => $trimestre) {

  $formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, '%spellout-ordinal');    
  print '<br>' . $formatter->format($key + 1) . ' trimestre<br>';

  foreach ($trimestre as $mes) {        
    print strftime('%B', mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes)) . '<br>' ;
  }

}
```

Uso `setlocale()` para que los valores de fecha y hora queden en español. Así puedo obtenerlos con `strftime()` y evito escribir los nombres de los meses a mano uno por uno ^_^.

Uso `NumberFormatter()` para obtener el ordinal del número de trimestre. Esto en inglés sale perfecto, porque queda 1st, 2nd, 3rd y 4th. En español se limita a agregarle 'º' al lado del número.

Con `range()` obtengo un array de números del 1 al 12, y con `array_chunk()` divido ese array en cuatro partes de 3 elementos cada uno, o sea, los trimestres. Resultando en esto:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 6
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
        [1] => 8
        [2] => 9
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 11
        [2] => 12
    )

)
```

Por último, con los `foreach` recorro los arrays y muestro el número de trimestre y el nombre del mes.

```
1º trimestre
enero
febrero
marzo

2º trimestre
abril
mayo
junio

3º trimestre
julio
agosto
septiembre

4º trimestre
octubre
noviembre
diciembre
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas. Las soluciones aportadas me parecen muy interesantes y las iré abordando para futuros desarrollos. Incluso en éste mismo, en una futura revisión que le haré pronto veré como puedo aplicarlo.

Por el momento, he aplicado esta solución. Al menos hace lo que necesito y por lo visto, bien y sin mucha carga:

```
$fact_meses_let_array = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");

if($fact_mes_registrado=="01"||$fact_mes_registrado=="02"||$fact_mes_registrado=="03"){
    $fact_meses_let_array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
    switch ($fact_mes_registrado){
        case "01":
            $fact_meses_let_array[2] = "Enero";
            break;
        case "02":
            $fact_meses_let_array[3] = "Febrero";
            break;
        case "03":
            $fact_meses_let_array[4] = "Marzo";
            break;
    }
} else if($fact_mes_registrado=="04"||$fact_mes_registrado=="05"||$fact_mes_registrado=="06"){
    $fact_meses_let_array[5] = "2do Trimestre";
    switch ($fact_mes_registrado){
        case "04":
            $fact_meses_let_array[6] = "Abril";
            break;
        case "05":
            $fact_meses_let_array[7] = "Mayo";
            break;
        case "06":
            $fact_meses_let_array[8] = "Junio";
            break;
    }
} else if($fact_mes_registrado=="07"||$fact_mes_registrado=="08"||$fact_mes_registrado=="09"){
    $fact_meses_let_array[9] = "3er Trimestre";
    switch ($fact_mes_registrado){
        case "07":
            $fact_meses_let_array[10] = "Julio";
            break;
        case "08":
            $fact_meses_let_array[11] = "Agosto";
            break;
        case "09":
            $fact_meses_let_array[12] = "Septiembre";
            break;
    }
} else if($fact_mes_registrado=="10"||$fact_mes_registrado=="11"||$fact_mes_registrado=="12"){
    $fact_meses_let_array[13] = "4to Trimestre";
    switch ($fact_mes_registrado){
        case "10":
            $fact_meses_let_array[14] = "Octubre";
            break;
        case "11":
            $fact_meses_let_array[15] = "Noviembre";
            break;
        case "12":
            $fact_meses_let_array[16] = "Diciembre";
            break;
    }
}
```

No parece un código demasiado limpio, pero funciona bien. Luego con el array, solo imprimo los valores que hayan sido rellenados y así monto mi lista.

**ACTUALIZACION**

He planeado otra estrategia, que me parece algo mas limpia

```
$fact_meses_let_array = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
$fact_meses_nombres_array = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

...[AQUI HABRIA UN FOREACH]...

switch ($fact_mes_registrado){
    case "01":
    case "02":
    case "03":
        $fact_meses_let_array[1] = "1er Trimestre";
        $fact_meses_let_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado+1] = $fact_meses_nombres_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado-1];
        break;
    case "04":
    case "05":
    case "06":
        $fact_meses_let_array[5] = "2do Trimestre";
        $fact_meses_let_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado+2] = $fact_meses_nombres_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado-1];
        break;
    case "07":
    case "08":
    case "09":
        $fact_meses_let_array[9] = "3er Trimestre";
        $fact_meses_let_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado+3] = $fact_meses_nombres_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado-1];
        break;
    case "10":
    case "11":
    case "12":
        $fact_meses_let_array[13] = "4to Trimestre";
        $fact_meses_let_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado+4] = $fact_meses_nombres_array[(int)$fact_mes_registrado-1];
        break;
}
```

Al menos, así parece mas directa, con menos código y me evito usar condicionales dentro de otros condicionales.

Gracias a todos por la ayuda!